# SSRS 2012: report wizard in visual studio- column header formatting

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have some tables that needs to be created as sql server reporting services reports in visual studio. 
The reports will be exported to CSV.
The column headers need to have the exact same names as the underlying table, as it will be exported into analytics software from the CSV's. 
The problem is that report wizard formats my column headers, ie *CustomerName* would become *Customer Name*, with a space. 
Is there any way to use the same column name in the header? 
The Data Set column headers are correct, but in the report itself it gets formatted.

Some of the tables have over a 100 columns, which is why I am using the wizard.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's good news and bad news.

I've never really used the Report Wizard, but it does seem to be the best option in your case.

The bad news is, in my quick test with the wizard, there seems to be no option for formatting headers like you're suggesting in the report.

The good news is that these don't actually affect the CSV export.

When exporting a table to CSV, SSRS uses the textbox **DataElementName** property to determine the CSV header column, and of that's not present it uses the textbox **Name** property.

Testing with the simplest possible dataset:

```
create table csvtest (CustomerName varchar(100))

insert into csvtest select 'customer1'
insert into csvtest select 'customer2'
```

And adding this to a report through the wizard I get the same result as you, i.e. the table header row is **Customer Name**:

[image]

However, the actual CustomerName textbox just inherits the name of the source column:

[image]

The end results is that when you export the table to CSV, it doesn't consider the **Customer Name** value in the table header row and just creates the CSV column header as **CustomerName**, as required:

[image]

So if you can live with the report looking different than you might expect, the CSV export might be correct in spite of the quirks of SSRS.

I would recommend trying the CSV export based on the wizard and seeing how it looks.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, it works beautifully :) Should have tried that myself! You saved me a few hours

Comment: You're welcome, @Niel. I don't blame for you not running the export first, it hardly works the way you would expect after all! Glad it helped.